# Accessing $dom from an $on event declared inside a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made a directive, has a template, and inside the link, I have an event handler using `scope.$on`

```
angular.module('app').directive('navPills', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: '/partials/nav-pills.html',
      link: function(scope, element) {
          scope.$on('focusChanged', function(event, elemFocused) {
             // check if the focused item is part of the directive
             if (element.find(elemFocused).length > 0) { 
                // do something
             }
          });
      }
   }
});
```

When running this code, I run into errors when `focusChanged` is emitted.  It's because element is undefined within the event handler.

My question is, what is the solution around this?

Comment: Where is the event being broadcast or emitted from and what is it sending? Please create a simple demo

Comment: Yes please create a simple demo plnkr or jsfiddle.

Comment: elemFocused is the argument that the calling method pass to the receiver. What part of your code are emmiting the event?

Comment: Please add your $broadcast function.